# Display untracked files in Mercurial commit message

Tags: mercurial

When you do an `hg commit`, you get a list of the files that will be added. Is it possible to append a list of untracked files to the bottom of this list? I keep finding that I am forgetting to commit newly created files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pre-commit hook to display the results of `hg status --unknown` - and either fail when there are unknown files or simply display files and use its output to `hg add` and `hg commit --amend` to add them to the previous commit when needed.